# Pushing the Docker image to Container Registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am going through the Step 3: Push the Docker image to Container Registry on how to setup a docker image from Google Clound Engine to Kubernetes engine, from [the following link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app#step_3_push_the_docker_image_to) though:

$

```
docker push gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/modo:v1
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/6267453573146657250/modo]
6a2e5ee87a10: Preparing
a276c90a34a4: Preparing
d675dcbcf549: Preparing
d675dcbcf549: Retrying in 1 second
0829f83db381: Retrying in 1 second
db7b61b8aab8: Retrying in 5 seconds
c5b2ac536264: Waiting
6c08a5b7d8f4: Waiting
c5b2ac536264: Waiting
6c08a5b7d8f4: Waiting
50867bb8f5d7: Waiting
72d6c6f0ea06: Waiting
8686c6b8d999: Waiting
44b57351135e: Waiting
00b029f9aa09: Waiting
18f9b4e2e1bc: Waiting
unknown: Project 'modo:6267453573146657250' not found or deleted.
```

I am sure the ID '6267453573146657250' is valid since it's the only project I have on the cloud engine.

Comment: Is value of PROJECT_ID=6267453573146657250 or project:6267453573146657250?

Comment: @hoque PROJECT_ID=6267453573146657250

Comment: The PROJECT_ID is typically a human-readable name that you gave the project. Try using the display name of the project instead of that numeric ID.

Comment: @jbielick If you look above the anchor link in the google documentation I provided, you'll see that PROJECT_ID is a series of numbers, not a human-readable name.

Comment: I don't see a series of numbers anywhere on that page. Could you take a look at the answer I added and see if that helps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the Project ID for `PROJECT_ID`, not the project *number*.

[This guide explains where to find this info](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects)

[image]

Note that the **Project ID** in this example is `my-sample-project-191923`, not `314053285323`. The latter is the project *number*.

Comment: It accepts the image but it keeps reconnecting until "unknown: Project 'project:6267453573146657250' not found or deleted".

Comment: do you know your project ID? Could you paste it with `x`s in place of the numbers here? It still sounds like `PROJECT_ID` is not set correctly.